# Updating Parse Objects Only If They Are Newer Than A Certain Date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am currently reloading every object in my iOS app, every app launch and downloading them into an array (about 1000 objects almost).

I really want to be much more efficient and have realized that 99% of the time, entries already downloaded won't change, so I really would rather only download objects with an `updatedAt` date newer than any `updatedAt` dates stored in my local array (I'm caching).

Is there a `whereKey` method I can use to only call objects newer than a certain date or a way to check when the last cache happened? Second, is there I way I can replace older options if an updated version is present, as I add these to the list?

Answer (score 0):

when download a resource you need take care about `Response header` it content info of your resource. If request success in  `Response header` may content a special key: `Last-Modified`.

Save it for each request success. In next time, when request again, you not need download all resource. Just when you receive response, get `Last-Modified` from response header. Compare with old `Last-Modified` info, if it is same you're resource really uptodate.

Answer (score 0):

The createdAt field exists on all records.  Keep track of the last time you made a query.

```
// first time, initialize it to find all rows
self.lastQuery = [NSDate distantPast];

// get rows created after the last query
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:self.lastQuery];

// once the query is done, remember the date, save it however you save stuff in your app
self.lastQuery = [NSDate date];
```